# Android API below 21 material theme action bar - activity can`t extend ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

What I understood from Android API guide is that for backward comparability, if one need action bar like material theme (means primary color and primary dark for the "upper strip" etc.) so you need to add library appcompatv7 and extend ActionBarActivity and manipulate in some way the style files.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

1. My activity already extends other class (it`s java etc...). What can I do?
2. Consider above - Can someone give complete example of what I need to put in each style file in order to support the look and feel of material theme action bar in app with min API 16? Because the standart example is extend  ActionBarActivity and copy paste the regular code from the android API guide link

Comment: "My activity already extends other class" - you need to extend ActionBarActivity (actually its AppCompatActivity now in v22) no way around it, make your root class extend it. To the second part, just do a simple google search there are hundreds of examples out there.

Comment: "My activity already extends other class (its java etc...). What can I do?" -- well, if it is actually an activity, it is extending `Activity`, or something else that inherits from `Activity`. If you wish to use `appcompat-v7`, you will need to do *something* to tie in the backported action bar. For most developers, the simplest answer is to inherit from `AppCompatActivity` (or its predecessor, `ActionBarActivity`). With current versions of `appcompat-v7`, you can also elect to use `AppCompatDelegate` to try to tie in other activities into the backport, though I have not tried this.

Comment: @for3st  1. What you mean in root class - its simple 1 activity app? 2. When I extend ActionBarActivity its says the class is deprecated, why?

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have suggestions how can I design 1 activity app, when this activity needs to extend ListActivity? Thanks,

Comment: "when this activity needs to extend ListActivity?" -- it does not need to extend `ListActivity`. `ListActivity` provides fairly limited functionality. It is easy enough to use the `ListView` directly yourself. You are certainly welcome to create `AppCompatListActivity`, cloning [the functionality of `ListActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java) but inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`, if you want.